# Mystery Fluid leak on 2010 Subaru Forester

Tags: subaru, forester

[image]!

The wife pulled into the driveway this afternoon will a dark fluid dripping from the front left part of the car. It looked pooled up underneath where the coolant reservoir sits. I don't think it's motor oil. Any guesses on what this is? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Get some on your finger. What's it look like? What's it smell like?

Comment: Has on oil like smell but much thinner than motor oil.

Comment: Transmission fluid maybe?  The first picture has a bit of a reddish tint, but I can't tell if it's just the picture.

Comment: The different fluids are Engine Oil, Power Steering Fluid (generally the same stuff as transmission fluid), Transmission Fluid, Engine Coolant, and Windshield Wiper Fluid.  Often times you can tell by the smell, viscosity, and color.

Answer (score 1):

- Black/Brown - motor oil
- Blue with watery texture - Subaru Super Coolant
- Red with oily texture - Automatic Transmission Fluid.  The ATF lines hook up to the radiator on the front left of the hood.  Also used for power steering